# Exception: You must select all cells in a merged range to merge or unmerge them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to find the merged cells in my sheet, but when I run the code from the scripts editor i get this error.

Exception: You must select all cells in a merged range to merge or unmerge them.

When I log the varable initMonthRng[0].getA1Notation() it has a value so I know that it has worked but the exception is still there.  Any advice would be most appreciated.

The code that this is a part of is lengthy so I only put the lines that pertain to the exception listed in the Execution Log.

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet);
    var initMonthRng = ss.getRange("A1:E10").getMergedRanges();
```

Comment: I think the error is pretty self descriptive. You have selected range `A1:E10` but you have merged cells beyond that range so the script does not allow you to delete them. What is your goal? If it is just to delete the merged cells why don't you try the full range of your sheet?

Comment: Hi ! Could you please shara a sample image or sheet to ilustrate your current situation along with a desired vs actual output? Also, what are the cells that are actually merged? Thanks !